# Laurent Series for singularities and poles

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series, singularity

Hi guys I was wondering how I can understand if the sin and the cos has essential singularities. for instance if I want to understand if 0 which singularity is i, can write the Laurent series only of the sin (centred in 0) and see how it works , or MUST write the Laurent series of all the function (centered in zero) ?
Same for cos , help I want to understand this topic very well. Thk.

> $$\int_{+\partial D}\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{z}\right)\cos\left(\dfrac{1}{z-2}\right)}{z-5}\,\mathrm{dz}$$

Comment: ok sorry , i was tryng to write the laurent series but it's difficoult so i want to understand if i have to write the resultin series of all the functions o i can just write the series of the sin( for instance) to understan which singularity is

Comment: you only need to write down the Laurent series for $\sin (1/z)$ centered at $0$. The other part $\cos (1/(z-2))/(z-5)=c_0+ c_1z+c_2z^2+\text{...}$ is analytic inside the unit disk. Then multiply the two series

Comment: @Lozenges  so for instance if i want to see if z=2 is an essential singularity i just wtrite the cos (1/(z-2)) series centered in 2 ??

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $f$ is an entire function, let $a \in \mathbb C$ and define $g(z):=f(\frac{1}{z-a})$ for $z \ne a$.

We have $f(z)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ for all $z$ (Taylor).

Then we get

$g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{(z-a)^n}$ for $z \ne a$ (Laurent).

Now you see: $a$ is an essential singularity of $g \iff f$  is not a polynomial.

Comment: so to see if they are essential singularities i can use the laurent serie only of the sin or the cos ? o o i have to write the serie of all the functions and see the resulting series?

Comment: and why i can study only the sin if it's possible ?